# How does one use local notifications and remote notifications without causing duplicates?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

How do I use local notifications and remote notifications without causing duplicates? If my app has connected and downloaded the notification to trigger locally, I only want app users who haven't been online recently to receive a push notification.

React Native, Firebase FCM, iOS & Android.

Comment: "Receive push notification" . I don't think you can stop receiving push notifications programmatically to avoid duplicates, this is something you need to handle on server side for the user , maybe a boolean to indicate hasReceivedNotf = 1/0 . Also, iOS does not know what users have been online recently for your app. this is something you should know as the server administrator.